# To display a link if the user is logged in

Tags: jstl

I want to dispaly a href only if the user has logged in vs not logged in 
Your Favorites

```
            <div id="shop-lists-response">
                <jsp:include page="/includes/sidebars/current-list-sidebar.jsp" flush="true"/>
            </div>  
        </c:when>

        <c:otherwise>
            <jsp:include page="/includes/sidebars/login_sidebar.jsp" flush="true"/>
        </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring security, the `<sec:authorize>` tag. See [taglib overview](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html).